# Using C# to create a new array from deserialized json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to use C# to restructure a JSON response into a more desirable format.

I have the following json structure:

```
[{"id":"1127889"},{"id":"1075442"}, {"id":"1201544"}]
```

I have used the following code to deserialize it:

```
var IDList = json.Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDList>)
```

I am trying to restructure the data in the following format:

```
{"ID":["123235", "nvnhlkisd", "1812dhd"]}
```

I am having trouble with task and have tried many options to no avail.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: its not clear from your example how to get from the first thing to the second thing

Comment: try `var ids = IDList.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();   var result = new { ID: ids }`

Comment: But the IDs in the second sample are not the same as from the first sample. What should that transformation look like? Where do those values come from? If there is no transformation, fix the samples. As it is, the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could approach this with `Newtonsoft.Json`. Create an entity class:

```
class Entity
{
   [JsonProperty("id")]
   public string Id;
}
```

Then get a list of entities:

```
var json = "[{\"id\":\"1127889\"},{\"id\":\"1075442\"}, {\"id\":\"1201544\"}]";
var workingObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(json);

var idList = new { id = (from c in workingObject select c.Id).ToArray()};
```

Comment: The workignObject that you mentioned is returning <null,null> keyvalue pair.

Comment: @ChandanGupta yeah, JSON.NET doesn't seem to play well with generic lists of key-value pairs. I've amended the answer to rely on a separate entity class.